# HashMap toJson is empty with JSON

Tags: java, moshi

the output of the following:

```
private static class Target extends HashMap<String, String> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Moshi build = new Moshi.Builder().build();
    final JsonAdapter<Target> adapter = build.adapter(Target.class);
    final Target value = new Target();
    value.put("foo", "bar");
    System.out.println(adapter.toJson(value));
}
```

is `{}` - I would expect `{"foo":"bar"}` - how do I get the expected output?

Comment: Side unrelated note : be careful when inheriting classes such as HashMap. It is a better practice to implement Map interface and holding a reference to a HashMap in the class, forwarding the put, get... methods to the HashMap. The reason is that you are linked to implementation details which is not good and might break compatibility when switching from a version of Java to another one. From Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 16 : `Unlike method invocation, inheritance violates encapsulation`... I strongly encourage you to read more about it ! That said, simply use the interface in JsonAdapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Map class not Target while creating JsonAdapter

```
private static class Target extends HashMap<String, String> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Moshi build = new Moshi.Builder().build();
    final JsonAdapter<Map> adapter = build.adapter(Map.class);
    final Target value = new Target();
    value.put("foo", "bar");
    System.out.println(adapter.toJson(value));
}
```